# Implementing Filterable on Array Adapter

Tags: java, android

I need help in implementing filterable interface for my list view items in a note app am currently working on. I have tried several ways but am not getting the expected result. For now it just does nothing after tying a search item.
I have implemented all the necessary methods in my adapter class and main activity.
 I really need some help as i am quite new to this.Thanks in anticipation for positive replies.

```
 //   Note.java
    public class Note implements Serializable {

    private long mDateTime; //creation time of the note
    private String mTitle; //title of the note
    private String mContent; //content of the note

    public Note(long dateInMillis, String title, String content) {
        mDateTime = dateInMillis;
        mTitle = title;
        mContent = content;
    }


    public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
        mDateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle = title;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        mContent = content;
    }

    public long getDateTime() {
        return mDateTime;
    }


    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }
}

   // ArrayAdapter which implements Filterable




 class NoteListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> implements Filterable{
    List<Note> objects;
    private List<Note> mStringFilterList;
     Filter filter;
    private static final int WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH = 5;
    public NoteListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Note> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
      this.mStringFilterList = objects;

    }

   @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return objects.size();
   }

    @Nullable
   @Override
    public Note getItem(int position) {
       return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                ArrayList<Note> tempList=new ArrayList<Note>();
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null && objects != null) {
                    for(Note singleNote : objects) {
                        if( singleNote.getTitle().contains(constraint))
                            tempList.add(singleNote);
                    }
                    results.values = tempList;
                    results.count = tempList.size();
                }

                return results;
            }


   @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        objects = (ArrayList<Note>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
};
return filter;
}



  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_component, parent, false);
  }

        return convertView;
    }


}

// Main Activity



     @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            ArrayList<Note> notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(getApplicationContext());
            final NoteListAdapter na = new NoteListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_component, notes);
            na.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning super.getFilter() instead of your filter you just created. And also, you're not filtering anything in the Filter `performFiltering()` method as you're adding every item to the results if the `CharSequence` has something and the adapter has items.

I would suggest something like that:

```
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
   ArrayList<Note> tempList=new ArrayList<Note>();
   FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
   if (constraint != null && objects != null) {
      for(Note singleNote : objects) {
         if( singleNote.getTitle().contains(constraint)
           tempList.add(singleNote);
      }
      results.values = tempList;
      results.count = tempList.size();
   }

   return results;
}
```

**EDITS:**

Also, in the activity, inside the

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
   ArrayList<Note> notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(getApplicationContext());
   final NoteListAdapter na = new NoteListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_component, notes);
   na.getFilter().filter(query);
   return false;
}
```

You're using a new adapter without setting it to the recyclerView/listView.
Try using the adapter you create inside the `onCreate()` of the activity or try using `recyclerView/listView`.`setAdapter(na)` after you change the adapter using the `na.getFilter().filter(query);`

---

**EDITS2:**

So, if you want your filter to be performed whenever the user input something move the code from the `onQueryTextSubmit()` to the `onQueryTextChanged()`.

For the improvement you asked for (when the string is empty reload the full list) you have 2 ways:

First way:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChanged(String query) {
   if (!query.equals("")) {
      ArrayList<Note> notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(getApplicationContext());
      final NoteListAdapter na = new NoteListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_component, notes);
      na.getFilter().filter(query);
   } else {
      ArrayList<Note> notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(getApplicationContext());
      final NoteListAdapter na = new NoteListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_component, notes);
   }
   return false;
}
```

The other way could be inside the `performFiltering()` method of the Filter interface implementation. You could also check if the string is empty there, and if so you need to return the full list, without creating a new support one in which you add elements only if certain condition are match.

Comment: i have implemented ur solution as you advised but am getting the same result. could you please review my code?

Comment: try removing the `if` statement in the `publishResults()` and always call the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: i appreciate ur help but it gives same result.

Comment: do i need to add something to onQueryTextSubmit in Main Activity?

Comment: omg, didn't see you were creating a NEW adapter. You don't have to create a new adapter. Use the adapter you use to display items or set the new adapter as the adapter of the recyclerView with `recyclerView.setAdapter(na)`

Comment: oops. thanks for spotting that out. ure amazing. problem is fixed now. However, i have this one last question to ask. am sorry if am quite demanding.

Comment: how do i make the search functionality more active? for example, for now i have to click on the search icon after typing a letter for the search to be implemented. i dont want that. i want the search to filter items immediately the user starts typing and the listview/recycler view to return to normal once the search view is empty. can u give me a clue around this?